# Zend Framework: Is there any zend framework function to echo link/anchor?

Tags: php, zend-framework

In CakePHP there is function like=>

```
echo $this->Html->link('name',array(...));
```

Is there anything like that in zend framework to echo link/anchor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this in your view:

```
<?php

echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'controllerName','action'=>'actionName','anchor'=>'#something'));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing is the [`Zend_View_Helper_Url`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/_View_Helper_Url.html#%5CZend_View_Helper_Url) object, but that is more like an internal route tool. I don't believe that there is a generic anchor tag generator though.